# mathjax \sqrt command

Tags: macros, math-operators, mathjax

I don't if this forum is the right place where post my question, anyway, it concerns TeX.

Mathjax seems to create the bar over the argument of `\sqrt` command as a box with a sequence of very densely dashes, as showed in the picture below. Is there a way to get this result into plain TeX environment?[image]

Comment: Well, since you ask how to do something in TeX, and not how to do it in MathJaX, I think it's on-topic. However, I don't understand what do you want: TeX makes the bar as a rectangle basically. Why should it matter?

Comment: Does it have to be Plain TeX, or can it be LaTeX?

Comment: @tohecz It's just a curiosity. I've seen that result also into a school book, but surely it was edited with an external software like InDesign or QuarkXpress

Comment: @Mico It should be also in LaTeX, of course. I'm asking for TeX because I prefer to avoid additional packages.

Comment: @Lorenzo Just to be clear: do you want the blue rectangle with the dashes?

Comment: @egreg Ops, that rectangle is for point out the dashes in the html pages where I copy that formula. Anyway, no, I don't want that rectangle!

Comment: @Lorenzo Then just `$L=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\cdots}}}}$` will do.

Comment: @egreg Ok, this is the real Plain TeX, but I'm asking for a macro that realises the `\root` and `\of #1` as mathjax seems to do, so with a overline bar formed by a sequence of dashes

Comment: I guess that it is only a matter of font glyphs. Mathjax makes use of a lot of dashes to produce a stretchable segment.

Comment: @Lorenzo Why would you want that? I can't understand. TeX draws a rule as wide as needed.

Comment: @egreg I understand, this is a 'strange' question, but it arises from the reading of some math books (in pdf, obviously, and too bad edited with external software) from which I noticed this case. I'm wondering if it could be reproduced in TeX.

Comment: @Lorenzo I can't see any purpose for it.

Comment: TeX makes a solid rule for radicals - see rule 11 in Appendix G of the TeXBook.  If you want a dashed rule you will need to resort to tikz or pstricks or similar and draw it as a graphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post a partial answer to my problem: I actually get the bar of the radicand as a densely sequence of dashes, but I also need to tell TeX how it has to raise this bar (see below).

```
    \newsymbol\trattino 1039 %to get dashes over the argument of the root (amssym.tex needed)
    \newbox\radicandobox
    \newbox\trattinobox
    \def\radice#1#2{%
        \setbox\trattinobox\hbox{$\mathord\trattino$}% the dash as a symbol
        \setbox\radicandobox\hbox{$#2$}
            \sqrt{\vphantom{\vrule height\ht\radicandobox depth\dp\radicandobox}}% a \sqrt contains an invisible line, which dimensions are those of radicand
                {\raise#1\ht\radicandobox% the overbar formed by dashes is raised of #1 from its natural heigth
                    \hbox to\wd\radicandobox{% the overbar itself
                        \xleaders\hbox to.5\wd\trattinobox{\hss$\mathord\trattino$\hss}\hfill}}%
            \kern-\wd\radicandobox{#2}% the radicand is replaced under the bar (dashed bar)
    }

    $\radice{1.2}{a}, \radice{.92}{2},\radice{.87}{2+b}, \radice{1.1}{\alpha+\radice{.92}{2}}, \radice{.975}{\displaystyle{a+b\over c}}$
```

I don't know if there is a way to fix that heigth and consequently solve this problem definitely. Anyway, this could be the right track.